# Laravel Models properties declaration

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
 private string $first_name;

 public function name()
 {
  return $this->first_name;
 }
}
```

when I call that method from a controller, I'm getting

> User::$first_name must not be accessed before initialization

Also, if I'm commenting/removing the declaration of property, the method runs well with no errors.

Comment: Hi @cristisst, What is returned if you remove the property declaration? I assume it is `null` but I just want to make sure.

Comment: the value of first_name not `null`

Comment: So. "What is returned if you remove the property declaration?"

Comment: Also note that the property `$first_name` will not map to the element in the database. If you have a field in the database called `first_name` then the class property will overshadow the database field and hence the uninitialised error.

Comment: you can solve the problem Defining An Accessor, see document https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators

Comment: if I remove the declaration of the property, then I'm getting the value from the database of `first_name`. it's really weird.

Comment: I don't understand why you're declaring a property on an Eloquent model. You don't do this in Eloquent for database fields - Eloquent doesn't work that way. The only time you should declare a property on an Eloquent model is when it's something used by Eloquent, such as the `$table` property. If you want to provide more info for an IDE or static analysis you need to use the @propery annotation on the class instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP 7.4 introduced typed properties.
Typed properties need to be initialised before accessing it. You can read more about that error in [this](https://madewithlove.com/blog/software-engineering/typed-property-must-not-be-accessed-before-initialization/) article

> That's why typed properties without a default value now have an
> uninitialized state. When calling a method that accesses such an
> uninitialized state, you'll get the "Typed property User::$username
> must not be accessed before initialization" error.
>
> Note that nullable typed properties also have this uninitialized state
> instead of having null as default value.

So simply initialising it will fix the error: `private string $first_name = "init value";`

But since you reference `Models` in the question title I assume you are using Eloquent models.

```php
class User extends Authenticatable {
    ...
}
```

And then you also don't need to put the model properties on the class. Eloquent will automatically map the database fields as properties on the object.

Comment: You don't need to extend `Model` on the `User` class as the `Authenticatable` class extends it.

Comment: The `Authenticatable` I imported is an `interface` so you do need to extend `Model`. If you import `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable` (as I've seen in many examples) then, yes, you only need to extend `Authenticatable`.

Comment: My point was; replacing the default `User extends Authenticatable` with `User extends Model implements Authenticatable` is pointless.

Comment: But not incorrect. It wasn't always the default so thats where the mixup happened. Thanks. Ill edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) to achieve this:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
 public function getNameAttribute()
 {
  return $this->first_name;
 }
}
```

Instead of calling the method, you only access a property with `get` prefix and `Attribute` suffic removed like so: `$user->name`